# Why the result is different for SQL string equality and for LIKE operator in Postresql?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, sql-like

I have a table with login names. Login names does not contain any special character just `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and of type varchar(50).

I would like to find a user by login name eg.:

```
CREATE TABLE users( login character varying(50) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('user1');
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('user2');

SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE ...;
```

What is the difference between `login LIKE 'exactMatch'`, `login LIKE 'exactMatch%'` and `login = 'exactMatch'`

I would expect that for this two-row database the following conditions both return the same result:

```
login LIKE '%user1'
login LIKE 'user1%'
login = 'user1'
login LIKE 'user1'
```

In some cases, for more complicated login names the last two conditions fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "work" or do not"? Also, what else should `login='user1'` in the select clause return than true?

Comment: `login LIKE 'exactMatch%'` means "starts from `exactMatch`": `exactMatch` followed by zero or more arbitrary symbols. Note, that `Like` is a wildcard where `_` - arbitrary symbol and `%` - zero or more arbitrary symbold

Comment: You should try to reproduce the problem in the [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com).

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean wheter it returns a single row where the field login is 'user1' or not.

Comment: @Leonard Unfortunatelly it works on dbfiddle, and also works with some usernames, but I cannot recognize any pattern. Unfortunately I cannot copy the exact login names due the privacy.

Comment: One difference in the query plan:
with ```login LIKE 'user1'``` the engine uses index scan with condition ((login)::text='user1'::text) + filter
while ```login LIKE 'user1%'``` uses sequential scan + filter

Comment: `SELECT login='user1'` does not do any filtering. What do you expect from that condition? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase, I thought that if a row existed where the value of login is  'user1' then both equality and pattern match would find that row.

Comment: What do you mean by "find that row"? If a row was returned, it was returned. But "the following query returns true" makes no sense here, as "true" is not a common result of any database query

Comment: @JónásBalázs If it works with some data then probably the problem is not with the query, but with the data. Are you sure that there are not any other special characters or whitespaces inside some usernames?  It's a long shot but, in the condition, if you try trim(login) = 'username' instead of login =  'username' does this gives you the expected result?

Comment: @Leonard I checked that md5(login) = md5('user1') was true. But trim seems working. How is it possible? What is funny, that ```SELECT login=trim(login) where trim(login)='user1'``` returns true. So what trim really does?

Comment: @JónásBalázs trim removes all whitespaces from the beginning and from the end of a given string. This means that you have at least one whitespace at the end of your username. But again, if md5 gives equality this means that the strings are the same.

Comment: @JónásBalázs Probably you're not looking at the same data.

Comment: Maybe IntelliJ do some character conversion in the background.

Comment: How should IntelliJ be involved in this whole process? How do you run the queries?

Comment: "for more complicated login names the last two conditions fail" - please share example for these complicated names, share what "fail" means, and what you've tried to check **why** this is not working as expected

Comment: @NicoHaase I run the queries with IntelliJ not from command line.

Comment: Meanwhile we figured it out that the index was corrupted. Pattern match didn't use the index, but sequential scan so it could find the row, while equality used index scan. It is a restored database and something went wrong during the restore. Reindexing solved our problem

Comment: Your example need to demonstrate the problem.  Yours instead demonstrates the absence of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, lets answer the question you asked:

> What is the difference between login LIKE 'exactMatch', login LIKE 'exactMatch%' and login = 'exactMatch'

`login LIKE 'exactMatch'` and 'login = 'exactMatch'` are equivalent.

When you put a `%` or `_` into the string, you get into `LIKE`'s pattern matching features.  When you have `login LIKE 'exactMatch%'`, you will get logins that start with 'exactMatch' followed by any number of characters.

Now, the problem I think you describe at the end is that you are finding that you have to use `%` in your LIKE clauses to get the matches you expect.  I would guess that this is due to there actually being unexpected characters in your login's or possibly an issue with character sets.

You might find the problem by running a query that looks for non-printable characters and strips out whitespace from the logins:

```
SELECT login FROM users
WHERE login <> trim(regexp_replace(login, '[^[:print:]]', 'x', 'g'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Several operators and wildcards can be used in SQL when working with strings to match patterns.
Following is the main difference between the three conditins which you mentioned in your question.

**login LIKE 'exactMatch' and login = 'exactMatch'**
Rows where the login column exactly matches 'exactMatch' will satisfy both of these conditions. Both of these require an exact, case-sensitive match for 'exactMatch'.

**login LIKE 'exactMatch%'**
This condition will match rows where the login column starts with 'exactMatch'. A wildcard, % matches any string of characters that comes after 'exactMatch'.

The outcome of the second query of your question is a result set rather than a boolean. The result will be a list of rows, each with a single column that has a boolean value indicating whether or not the row's login column begins with "user1." While this is an uncommon application of the SELECT statement, the SQL query is however valid.

The COUNT function can be used if you want to count the number of rows that satisfy this condition, it will give you the count of rows where the login column starts with 'user1'.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users
WHERE login LIKE 'user1%';
```